# Get specific StringValue from a list of RegistryKeys with Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

Im trying to create a Powershell script that can show me a list of all the Registry Keys from "Test" (Screenshot1).
[image]
Every Key has a StringValue "Version". I need to know the value from each.
The output should be something like this:

Sub1 Version: 112
Sub2 Version: 112
Bus3 Version: 111

I also would need to know the value of "Server" from Setting of each Key. (Screenshot2)
[image]
It should look something like this in the end:

Sub1 Version: 112 Server: 2012
Sub2 Version: 112 Server: 2008
Bus3 Version: 111 Server: 2012

I've tried to get it working by using "get-childitem" and "get-itemproperty", but failed in the end due to lack of experience. I don't understand how to get it to work to show me the desired output. Does anyone have an idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried and explain how it did not work along with any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
$file = "c:\temp\RegistryValues.txt"

$items = Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Test\*"
$items2 = $items | select -ExpandProperty name  

$items2 | % { 

    $i = $(($_).split("\")[-1])
    $j = $(Get-ItemPropertyValue "Registry::$_" -Name 'version')
    $k = $(Get-ItemPropertyValue "Registry::$_\Setting" -Name 'Server')

"$i Version: $j Setting: $k" | add-content $file


}
```

Comment: What makes you think that? I don't see anything in that code that I think is 5.1+

Comment: @EBGreen I'll edit it to 5.0. (Get-ItemPropertyValue)

Comment: Who is still using anything older?  PS works everywhere.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns I have many servers, some of them run on 2012R2 (Powershell v.4.0 is standard here). I can't update Powershell on there because I can only restart these machines a few times per year.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample script that doesn't exactly answer your question.  But it shows how to access the registry keys and values.

```
function ShowDotNetVersion
{
  # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx
  $p = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" -Name Release -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  if ($p -eq $null) { $rc = "UNKN" }
  else { $rc = $p.Release.ToString() }

  if ($rc -eq "378389") { $rc = ".NET 4.5" }
  if ($rc -eq "378675") { $rc = ".NET 4.5.1/Windows 8.1" }
  if ($rc -eq "378758") { $rc = ".NET 4.5.1" }
  if ($rc -eq "381023") { $rc = ".NET 4.5.1/Windows 10/9860" }
  if ($rc -eq "381029") { $rc = ".NET 4.5.1/Windows 10/9896" }
  if ($rc -eq "394254") { $rc = ".NET 4.6/Windows 10" }

  Write-Host ".NET framework $rc is installed"

  $p = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" -Name Version -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Version.ToString()
  Write-Host ".Net framework version is $($p)"
}
```

This is part of my powershell startup script so I run it multiple times per day.  Maybe it can inspire you to self-answer your own question.